# Bertrand's Ballot Theorem

Tags: mathematics, probability

A total of X voting papers for candidate A and Y voting papers for candidate B were cast in one section during the election. Where X > Y

At the end of election day, the voting papers were counted manually, with one voting paper taken at random. Each time the voting paper is taken, the count for the candidate whose name is on the voting paper is increased.

What is the probability that in the course of the census there was a moment when the currently counted votes for candidate A were equal to the currently counted votes for candidate B?

Comment: @JLee, it does not looks like quite right because after all the voting papers for Peter are picked there is no chance for a tie but there will be a chance to some voting papers for George to be not yet picked

Comment: I did not find the simulation from you but the probability cannot be close to 100% because you can take every George, than again George and after that rotate George, Peter, George, Peter… and in that case you will never have a tie. The other option is to take three times George and then again rotate them, etc, etc, so there are a lot of options to not have a tie

Comment: Spoiler: This is [Bertrand's Ballot Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem)

Comment: The theorem gives the probability of them *never* being equal (except for the 0,0 at the start). The probability you are looking for is 1 minus that, i.e. the probability that it does become equal at least once.

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $y$ be the current number of votes for $B$, and $x$ be the number of current votes for $A$. If $y>x$ at any time, then $x=y$ at some point in this count. So we have to find the probability that $y>x$ at some time. The chance this happens in the very first vote is $\frac{Y}{Y+X}$. But for every one of these sequences where $B$ starts ahead, and $A$ eventually catches up, there is an equal number of sequences where $A$ starts ahead and $B$ eventually catches up, so we have to double this probability, and so the answer is $\frac{2Y}{X+Y}$.

Comment: This is a really elegant solution!

Comment: I don't quite understand why it is necessarily true that there has to be an equal number of sequences where A starts ahead and B catches up.

Comment: @Sid You can construct a bijection I believe. Call $M$ the set of sequences where $B$ starts ahead, and $N$ the set of sequences where $A$ starts ahead, but there is a tie at some point. For $a \in M$, letting index $i$ be where there is a tie, we may reverse the first $i$ entries, and calling this new sequence $a'$, we see that $a' \in N$, as there will still be a tie, and $A$ starts ahead. Clearly this is an injective function, and it's also surjective as well(just apply function on an element in $N$ and note that it lies in $M$). So $M \simeq N \implies |M|=|N|$, as desired.